# What is the good practice breaking up Game1()

Tags: design-patterns, xna

It is growing too many textures/vectors in the "Game1.cs". The Draw and Update are also bigger and not manageable easily. How you guys doing it?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but perhaps some inspiration here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5459955/165500

Answer (score 5):

This is a very open ended question. If your code is becoming too complex use additional types to handle specific responsibilities.

For XNA take a look at the [GameComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.aspx) and [DrawableGameComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.drawablegamecomponent.aspx) classes. That will get you started, but you probably need to introduce additional types. Get a good book on object oriented design to get some ideas.