# Passing constructors with arguments?

Tags: c#, constructor, xna, arguments

Hello I have a problem passing the constructor with argument of my class. There it is:

```
    // Non-static variables exist once for each instance of the class
    Vector2 position;

    public Vector2 Position { get { return position; } }
    public myClass(Vector2 position)
    {
        this.position = position;
    }
```

I'm trying to instance it like this (`Game1` class):

```
myClass myClassInstance;

protected override void Initialize()
{
    // TODO: Add your initialization logic here.
    myClassInstance = new myClass(Position);
    base.Initialize();
}
```

But I get this error at `Initialize()`:

```
Error   1   The name 'Position' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. In your Initialize() there doesn't seem to be a variable called Position which is why it's giving you that error.

Comment: @Haedrian is in the Game1 class. I used this answer for my code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11383467/3944196

Comment: Please I really need some help about this...

Comment: If you want help, then post a good, complete, concise code example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. As it stands, no one can tell what the relationship between your `Initialize()` method and whatever type that contains the `Position` property is. Obviously they are not in the same type, but it's not clear at all what value you should be passing to the constructor instead of the erroneous "Position".

Comment: I posted a link in the previous comment... Anyway I got it solved. I entirely removed the instance which in fact was only used for a duplicated `Draw()` method. Now the entire game functions properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Initialize method does not have any kind of "Position" variable declared in scope.  For example, you might do something like this:

```
myClass myClassInstance;

protected override void Initialize()
{
    // variables defined in a function are typically lower-case in C#
    Vector2 position = new Vector2(0,0);

    // I changed "Position" to "position" to match the variable
    myClassInstance = new myClass(position);
    base.Initialize();
}
```

However the bigger problem here may be that you need to spend a little time getting up-to-speed on your C# before continuing, as this is probably the first of many problems you'll run into if the syntax doesn't make sense to you.  Here's a great video series to start with:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMUNVW3VsMWUB9mPN10vU6jvc_jbHvs1g