# XNA draw : using one spritebatch at whole game

Tags: xna, spritebatch

I am developing an XNA game. This is time I am careful about the architecture. Til today, I have always implemented my own draw method in this way:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb, GameTime gameTime)
{
    sb.Begin();
    // ... to draw ...
    sb.End();
}
```

I was digging the DrawableGameComponent and saw the Draw method comes in this way:

```
public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // ...
}
```

First of all, I know that SpriteBatch can collect many Texture2D between Begin and End, so that it can be useful to sort them, or draw with same Effects.

My question is about the performance and the cost of passing the SpriteBatch. At DrawableGameComponent it is possible to call spritebatch of game object if its spritebatch is public.

What is suggested, what should a xna-game programmer do?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the serious disadvantages of `DrawableGameComponent` is that you're locked into its provided method signature. While there's nothing "wrong", per se, with `DrawableGameComponent`, do not think of it as the "*one true architecture*". You're [better off](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9209/288) thinking of it as an example of a possible [architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5459955/165500).

If you find yourself needing to pass a `SpriteBatch` (or anything else) to the draw method of a "game component" - **the best way *is* to pass it as an argument**. Anything else is convoluted.

Obviously this means that you can't use XNA's provided `GameComponent` system, and you have to make your own alternative. But this is almost trivial: At its most basic level, it's just a list of some base type that has appropriate virtual methods.

---

Of course, if you must use `GameComponent` - or your game is so simple (eg: a prototype) that you don't really care about the architecture - then you can use basically *any* method you like to get a `SpriteBatch` to your draw method. They all have disadvantages.

Probably the next-most architecturally robust method is to pass your `SpriteBatch` instance into the constructor of each of your components. This keeps your components decoupled from your game class.

On the other hand, if you're throwing architecture to the wind, I'd suggest making your `MyGame.spriteBatch` field `public static`. This is the simplest way to allow it to be accessed anywhere. It's easy to implement and easy to clean up later when/if you need to.

---

To answer your question about performance: Anything to do with passing a `SpriteBatch` around will have almost negligible effect on performance (providing the order of calls to `Draw`/`Begin`/`End` stays the same). Don't worry about it.

(If you see `SpriteBatch whatever` in code, that represents a reference. A reference is a 32-bit value (in a 32-bit program, which all XNA games are). That's the same size as an `int` or a `float`. It's very small and very cheap to pass around/access/etc.)

Answer (score 5):

If you stumbled upon this question you were probably looking at a nice and generic solution. I would suggest you have a look at this:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14217/several-classes-need-to-access-the-same-data-where-should-the-data-be-declared/14232#14232

I felt the need to correct this question because *"the best way is to pass it as an argument. Anything else is convoluted."* is simply **not correct**.

Personally i am now doing it this way in my GameBase class:

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        SpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        this.Services.AddService(typeof(SpriteBatch), SpriteBatch);
    }
```

Now, since you're adding DrawableGameComponents in the Initialize Method of your Game class you will be able to call

```
    this.Game.Services.GetService(typeof(SpriteBatch))
```

I'd say that's the cleanest approach to solve the problem.

Comment: I'd disagree that this is the best approach. Using [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) in a game could have a significant amount of performance overhead if not wired up right. This requires you to register all of your Types ahead of time, even if the game never uses them during its life-cycle which is a waste of resources. Depending on your target device, and game type, resources could be very constrained. DI has it's place. I just don't agree it's place belongs in video games of any kind other than prototypes.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger The limitations you've mentioned are obviously right, since it's a very common "issue" with DI. It should be used with care, and monitored to avoid poor performance - but most people who gather experience with DI already know that

Answer (score 1):

If the `DrawableGameComponent` should be part of the parent's `SpriteBatch`, then just pass it in via the constructor and store it in a private member (or expose it as a property if you wish).

You could also expose the `SpriteBatch` as a property of your `Game` class if you wanted, like you suggested, but every time you referenced `this.Game`, you would need to cast it to your specific `Game` class type.

```
((MyGame)this.Game).SpriteBatch.Draw(...)
```

Or you can just have the `DrawableGameComponent` create a new `SpriteBatch`. There's nothing wrong with that (as far as I've ever seen). I suppose it depends how many `DrawableGameComponent`s you'll be creating and how often.

Also browse through the results for a [search for `DrawableGameComponent`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DrawableGameComponent&submit=search) - there's a lot of good advice there.